# How to play a GIF file in Android?

Tags: android, gif, android-image

I want to play a GIF file in my current activity.

I have an XML file in which there is a layout.

I want to play the GIF in the same class Activity.

Is there a simple way to play a GIF file in an Activity class?

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/how_to_play_gif_file_in_android-t3492.html

Comment: have you tried to show gif in webview?

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=1d6c2e915ad2ff0a&hl=en

Comment: convert gif in to .png files and apply frame animation

Comment: friends  i have 10 gif to run at diff action. and xml frame animation is nor allowed by our development. so if any budy nkow how to run gif by codind then plz tell me..

Comment: i think only previous way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't support the playing of animated GIF files. If you need to play them then you need to break them apart into frames, and animate each frame one by one.

This will let you split up the GIF file
http://www.xoyosoft.com/gs/

Comment: I am happy to get an answer but:   with the canvas we can easily play gif files.

Comment: No, you can't play GIF files, but once you have broken them apart into individual drawables, you can then animate those using AnimationDrawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use a webView.
I will show with an example:

```
//My activity
public class Gift_Loading extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Gif_loading_View view = new Gif_loading_View(this); 
        setContentView(view);
    }

}

//the webView
public class Gif_loading_View extends WebView{

    public Gif_loading_View(Context context) {

        super(context);     
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading_position.html");

        } 
}
```

In the assets folder add this html file:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">                
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font size="6">Please wait...</font>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <img src="cyclist_loading.gif" />

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/04/implement-custom-view-to-display.html) in which a custom `AnimatedGifView` class is created.

It makes use of the `android.graphics.Movie` class, and overrides the `onDraw` method to redraw the view periodically. Here's an excerpt:

```
gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.myGIFImage);
gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
gifMovie.setTime((int)movieRunDuration);
gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
```

It's probably more appropriate to [convert animated GIFs to `AnimationDrawables`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/01/converting-animated-gifs-animationdrawables.html), instead, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/first"
    />
```

Use the code and your gif file put into the drawable folder....
and change the name first with your gif file name.