# How to load the gif file on button click in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am new one in android. I want to load or play the `gif` image on button click. I load the two `gif` file on layout. But when I click the next button next, next image will be played, here where we write setonclickListener for button click.... how to play the `gif` image on button click in android. If you know please tell me.

Here is my code..

```
package com.androidqa;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class AnimationView extends View 
{
    private Movie mMovie,mMovie1;
    private long mMovieStart;
    private long mMovieStart1;
    Button btnFirst,btnSecond;
    private static final boolean DECODE_STREAM = true;
    private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) 
    {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int len;
     try 
     {
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      }
      return os.toByteArray();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static byte[] streamToBytes1(InputStream is1) 
    {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
     byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
     int len;
     try 
     {
        while ((len = is1.read(buffer1)) >= 0) {
          os1.write(buffer1, 0, len);
        }
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      }
      return os1.toByteArray();
    }

     public AnimationView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) 
     {
      super(context,attrs);
      setFocusable(true);
      java.io.InputStream is;
      java.io.InputStream is1;
      is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.th_welcome);
      is1 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animimage);
      if (DECODE_STREAM) 
      {
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        mMovie1=Movie.decodeStream(is1);
      } else 
      {
        byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
        byte[] array1 = streamToBytes1(is1);
        mMovie1= Movie.decodeByteArray(array1, 0, array1.length);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
     long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

      if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
        mMovieStart = now;
      }
      if (mMovie != null) 
      {
        int dur = mMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
          dur = 3000;
        }
        int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
       Log.d("", "real time :: " +relTime);
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - 200, getHeight()-200);
        invalidate();
      }
      if (mMovieStart1 == 0) { // first time
          mMovieStart1 = now;
        }
        if (mMovie1 != null) 
        {
          int dur = mMovie1.duration();
          if (dur == 0) {
            dur = 3000;
          }
          int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart1) % dur);
         Log.d("", "real time :: " +relTime);
          mMovie1.setTime(relTime);
          mMovie1.draw(canvas, getWidth() - 200, getHeight()-200);
          invalidate();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use simple frameanimation? AFAIK gif won't play in android.

Comment: Android does not support playing gif files, u will have to use animation if you want to play.

Comment: i want only load the gif image not jpg images.....frame animation many images can only animated....

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support the playing of animated GIF files. If you need to play them then you need to break them apart into frames, and animate each frame one by one.

Also see below link to more clearification :-

[How to play a GIF file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306846/how-to-run-gif-file-in-android)

[Is it possible to play GIF format in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163706/is-it-possible-to-play-gif-format-in-android)

Comment: i wrongly asked the questions....i dont want play the gif image...on button click the gif image will be loaded.....the gif image is loading layout without button click...i need when i click button that time gif image will be displayes or loaded.. thanks in advance.@HCD

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity write code that handles a button click. i.e:

```
static boolean clicked = false;

public void onClick(View v) {

clicked = true;
AnimationView.invalidate();

/* When I am referring to AnimationView, I mean the name of your AnimationView and not the class. */

}
```

And in your onDraw method make an if statement saying that the view is only invalidated if clicked is true.

Good luck