# How to make Moto G Globe animation in an app?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, motorola

We are building an Android app where in the place of splash screen while waiting, i want to add an animation just like [Boot animation of Moto G](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S27qEyvwIJw). Not exactly the same, but globe with some other elements will be used.

So my question is how to do it something like that?

Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: See an animation [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm)

Comment: It's not an animation, it's gif file!

Comment: This link might help http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/.... More info about spliting gif and other can be found at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306846/how-to-run-gif-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

as for android .. you have to make animation manually ..
for this make `xml` file with `animatiom-list` under `res/drawable` .. then add items and give duration ..

EXAMPLE:::::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false">
     <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/image1"
     android:duration="300"
     />
   <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/image2"
     android:duration="300"

     />
     <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/image3"
     android:duration="300"
     />
       <item 
     android:drawable="@drawable/image4"
     android:duration="300"
     />
```

`android:oneshot="false"` is to repeat animation again and again .. if you dont want to repeat then make it true

after you make animation .. add it in a `imageview` ..